# Filtering an Array to return grouped totals

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an efficient way to take a large Array of Objects and return the totals on certain properties, whilst still retaining some of the orginal data?

In our example we have an Array similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    Name: 'Bob',
    Month: January 2021,
    WorkCode: 'Fee1'
    Hours: 20,
    Salary: 400.00,
    ...
  },
  {
    Name: Bob',
    Month: January 2021,
    WorkCode: 'Fee2'
    Hours: 10,
    Salary: 200.00,
    ...
  },
  {
    Name: 'Bob',
    Month: January 2021,
    WorkCode: 'Fee3'
    Hours: 5,
    Salary: 100.00,
    ... 
  },
  {
    Name: 'Bob',
    Month: February 2021,
    WorkCode: 'Fee1'
    Hours: 15,
    Salary: 300.00,
    ...
  },
  {
    Name: 'Alice',
    Month: January 2021,
    WorkCode: 'Fee1'
    Hours: 10,
    Salary: 300.00,
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

I want to be able to return each person in the array with the sum of their hours and salary up to a selected date (assume that the Months in the example are `Date` objects).

At the moment I am using `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()` to give me a subset of the original data that contains all the raw data that I need.

```
let weekRows = data.filter((currentRow) => {
  return currentRow.Month <= maxDate
})
if (this.workCodeFilter.length !== 0) {
  weekRows = weekRows.filter((currentRow) => {
    return this.workTypeFilter.some((f) => {
      return f.WorkCode === currentRow.WorkCode
    })
  })
}
if (this.peopleFilter.length !== 0) {
  weekRows = weekRows.filter((currentRow) => {
    return this.peopleFilter.some((f) => {
      return f.psRef === currentRow.ps_ref
      })
    })
}
```

I then pass the `weekRows` data to a `for` loop which uses `findIndexByKeyValue` to lookup the Person and the WorkCode in a result array, and either add a new entry if its the first instance, or increment the totals for Hours and Salary if they already have an entry. This last stage is *very* slow

The end result should be totals for Salary and Hours, per person, up to the required Date.
It should also retain the additional data represented by the `...`

Filters should be possible for Date (always), and optionally WorkCode and/or Person. Both WorkCode and Person can have multiple entries, hence `Array.some()`

Am I right that `Array.reduce()` should be able to do what I am looking for, whilst also replacing the `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()` calls

Comment: do you have an example of call and wanted result from given data?

Comment: There should be one entry per person/selected WorkCode, so if only one WorkCode were selected there would be two entries. In the above example there will only be an Entry for Alice if “Fee1” is selected, or if no WorkCode is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you seek for [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you may leverage that together with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map):

- build up `Map`, having `Name` as a key and corresponding group total object as value (with date criteria as a bail out condition);
- extract array of group totals with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)

E.g.

```js
const srcData = [{Name:"Bob",Month:"January 2021",WorkCode:"Fee1",Hours:20,Salary:400},{Name:"Bob",Month:"January 2021",WorkCode:"Fee2",Hours:10,Salary:200},{Name:"Bob",Month:"January 2021",WorkCode:"Fee3",Hours:5,Salary:100},{Name:"Bob",Month:"February 2021",WorkCode:"Fee1",Hours:15,Salary:300},{Name:"Alice",Month:"January 2021",WorkCode:"Fee1",Hours:10,Salary:300}],
      strToDate = str => {
        const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December'],
              [month, year] = str.split(' ')
              return new Date(
                year,
                months.indexOf(month),
                1
              )
      }



      groupTotalTillDate = (src, maxDateStr) => [
        ...src
          .reduce((acc,{Name, Hours, Salary, Month}) => {
            if(strToDate(Month)>=strToDate(maxDateStr)) return acc
            const group = acc.get(Name)
            if(group){
              group.Hours += Hours
              group.Salary += Salary
            } else {
              acc.set(Name, {Name, Hours, Salary})
            }

           return acc
          }, new Map)
          .values()
      ]

console.log(groupTotalTillDate(srcData, 'February 2021'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: This doesn't filter by either Name or WorkCode. I assume that that would be handled in the same way as the Date check - escape the `reduce` if conditions do not match?

Comment: Alternatively is there any benefit in, as other have done, doing the `Array.filter()` before `Array.reduce()` - especially considerint that the WorkCode and Person filters may contain multiple values

Comment: @DanKelly: I replied your question under another solution. My method doesn't require extra looping through source array to filter out irrelevant records.

Comment: @DanKelly: You may benchmark my approach against the others, using something like jsbench.me, to figure out performance difference on some large array.

Comment: @yevgen-gobunkov Thanks for the comments, that's what I understood. 
One final question from trying to implement this... `const group = acc.get(Name)` matches only on `item.Name`. In the real world example I need to keep Person and WorkCode distinct.  Short of constructing a `Peroson_WorkCode` key, is there a different option to improve the `get()`?

Comment: @DanKelly : if I understood your requirement properly, you need to use (unique) combination of `Person` and `WorkCode` properties as a key for your `Map`. For that you may have those extra properties destructured (`src.reduce((acc,{Person, WorkCode..`) and get `Map` key variable `const mapKey = Person+'\ufffd'+WorkCode` and access `Map` records accordingly `const group = acc.get(mapKey)` and assign with `acc.set(mapKey, {..`.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter first and then take the accumulation of wanted values.

```js
const
    data = [{ Name: 'Bob', Month: '2021-01', WorkCode: 'Fee1', Hours: 20, Salary: 400 }, { Name: 'Bob', Month: '2021-01', WorkCode: 'Fee2', Hours: 10, Salary: 200 }, { Name: 'Bob', Month: '2021-01', WorkCode: 'Fee3', Hours: 5, Salary: 100 }, { Name: 'Bob', Month: '2021-02', WorkCode: 'Fee1', Hours: 15, Salary: 300 }, { Name: 'Alice', Month: '2021-01', WorkCode: 'Fee1', Hours: 10, Salary: 300 }],
    keys = ['Hours', 'Salary'],
    zeroProps = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, 0])),
    result = data
        .filter(({ Month }) => Month >= '2021-01')
        .reduce((hash => (r, { Name, ...o }) => {
            if (!hash[Name]) r.push(hash[Name] = { Name, ...zeroProps });
            keys.forEach(k => hash[Name][k] += o[k]);
            return r;
        })({}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array#reduce()` method to eliminate elements that have a month greater than the specified one; I would use the format `YYYY-MM`. Something like:

```
let fhours = hours.filter(h => h.Month < Month);
```

Then in the following demo you would replace the variable `hours` for `fhours` to get the summary of the filtered hours.

```js
let hours = [{
        Name: 'Bob',
        Month: '2021-01',
        WorkCode: 'Fee1',
        Hours: 20,
        Salary: 400.00
    },
    {
        Name: 'Bob',
        Month: '2021-01',
        WorkCode: 'Fee2',
        Hours: 10,
        Salary: 200.00
    },
    {
        Name: 'Bob',
        Month: '2021-01',
        WorkCode: 'Fee3',
        Hours: 5,
        Salary: 100.00
    },
    {
        Name: 'Bob',
        Month: '2021-02',
        WorkCode: 'Fee1',
        Hours: 15,
        Salary: 300.00
    },
    {
        Name: 'Alice',
        Month: '2021-01',
        WorkCode: 'Fee1',
        Hours: 10,
        Salary: 300.00
    }
];
console.log(hours.length);
console.log(hours.filter(h => h.Month < '2021-02').length);

let summary = hours.reduce((ac, cu) => ({
    ...ac,
    [cu.Name]: {
        Hours: ac[cu.Name].Hours + cu.Hours,
        Salary: ac[cu.Name].Salary + cu.Salary
    }
}), [...new Set(hours.map(h => h.Name))].reduce((a, c) => ({
    ...a,
    [c]: {
        Hours: 0,
        Salary: 0
    }
}), {}));

console.log(summary);
```

Comment: In your exampe, as well as a few others you are using `Array.filter()` to get the subset of data based on the Month, which is what I am already doing in production (as well as filtering on WorkCode and Person).

Is there a benefit in doing it this way, as opposed to the method proposed by @yevgen-gorbunkov ?

Comment: @DanKelly : performance-wise `.filter()+reduce()` takes 2 passes through source array, single `.reduce()` (in my solution) takes only one. Furthermore, in above solution, when `Set` is getting built, you do another array pass with `.map()`

Comment: @DanKelly : One advantage of using the `filter` and `reduce` combination is that, it improves code readability. From the filter statement it is clear that we are filtering the data based on a maximum date.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Name: "Bob",
    Month: new Date("01 January 2020"),
    WorkCode: "Fee1",
    Hours: 20,
    Salary: 400.0,
  },
  {
    Name: "Bob",
    Month: new Date("01 January 2021"),
    WorkCode: "Fee2",
    Hours: 10,
    Salary: 200.0,
  },
  {
    Name: "Bob",
    Month: new Date("01 February 2021"),
    WorkCode: "Fee3",
    Hours: 5,
    Salary: 100.0,
  },
  {
    Name: "Bob",
    Month: new Date("01 March 2021"),
    WorkCode: "Fee1",
    Hours: 15,
    Salary: 300.0,
  },
  {
    Name: "Alice",
    Month: new Date("01 January 2021"),
    WorkCode: "Fee1",
    Hours: 10,
    Salary: 300.0,
  },
];

const getTotals = (data, maxDate) => {
  const isEmployeeAddedInAcc = (acc, item) =>
    acc.find((emp) => emp.Name === item.Name);

  const updateDetails = (item) => (employee) =>
    employee.Name === item.Name
      ? {
          ...employee,
          Salary: employee.Salary + item.Salary,
          Hours: employee.Hours + item.Hours,
        }
      : item;

  const salaryReducer = (acc, item) =>
    isEmployeeAddedInAcc(acc,item)
      ? acc.map(updateDetails(item))
      : [...acc, { Name: item.Name, Hours: item.Hours, Salary: item.Salary }];

  return data.filter((item) => item.Month < maxDate).reduce(salaryReducer, []);
};

console.log(getTotals(data, new Date("27 February 2021")));
```